# Как узнать текущую глубину рекурсии в python?

Tags: python, рекурсия

Нагуглил, что вывести текущий лимит (1000 по умолчанию) и изменить его можно с помощью модуля `sys`. Но как вывести именно **текущую глубину погружения в рекурсию** в определенный момент времени? В `sys` такого не нашел. Например, что нужно добавить в `func_2` в таком коде, что бы печаталась глубина рекурсии **при каждом входе** в эту функцию?

```
def func_1():
    func_2()

def func_2():
    func_1()
```

Comment: `len(inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe()))`

Comment: о... то что мне и было нужно. спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ дали в комментариях, так что отвечу на собственный вопрос, может кому пригодится. За ответ спасибо **Danis**.

**`len(inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe()))`** позволяет вывести на печать текущую глубину рекурсии.

Столкнулся с проблемой рекурсии в `pygame` - у меня при начале новой игры из меню (без перезапуска программы) выполняется функция `mainloop()`, в которой содержится главный цикл игры. И каждый раз глубина рекурсии увеличивается примерно на 10. Примерно сотый перезапуск игры уронит её, так что проблема существенная. Тем более игры короткие, по минуте на попытку. В реальном проекте, наверное, за такое железной линейкой по пальцам бить надо, но я не стал полностью переписывать код программы, состоящей из нескольких модулей, и обошелся костылем. В функции с главным циклом добавил условие, которое увеличивает лимит рекурсии если её текущая глубина отстаёт меньше, чем на 100:

```
def mainloop(self):

if len(inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())) > sys.getrecursionlimit() - 100:
    sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() + 100)
```

Не очень красивое решение, но работает!

Comment: Да лучше уж сразу тогда установить лимит рекурсии максимально возможный и не париться. Хотя на разных системах с разным интерпретатором питона этот лимит разный может быть.

Comment: @CrazyElf не хотелось бы испытывать систему без необходимости. лучше подгружать лимит, если до этого вообще дойдет. тем более я эту тему не настолько освоил, где какие лимиты и к чему ещё это может привести пока не знаю. стараюсь без необходимости такие настройки не крутить не разобравшись